# nslookup is OK, but curl says Couldn't resolve host

Tags: curl, nslookup

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.3.1/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
101   405    0   405    0     0    403      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  1673
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 's3.amazonaws.com'
```

I'm using an internal DNS server

```
nslookup s3.amazonaws.com
Server:     10.162.55.134
Address:    10.162.55.134#53

Non-authoritative answer:
s3.amazonaws.com    canonical name = s3.a-geo.amazonaws.com.
s3.a-geo.amazonaws.com  canonical name = s3-1.amazonaws.com.
Name:   s3-1.amazonaws.com
Address: 54.231.8.80
```

getent result(I have executed the cmd many times and always get the same output):

```
$ getent ahosts s3.amazonaws.com
54.231.9.24     STREAM s3-1.amazonaws.com
54.231.9.24     DGRAM
54.231.9.24     RAW
```

Comment: What does `getent ahosts s3.amazonaws.com` say? That should be more in line with what `curl` will do (uses the system resolver to look up the name).

Comment: I'd suggest checking a traceroute, and then seeing where it stops replying. The command is traceroute s3.amazonaws.com

Comment: Can you clarify whether you can still reproduce the original problem?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I'm afraid not, it's unstable,  I try serveral times then it works. nslookup is always OK, and curl failed many times until last time it success